# Echonest API - retrieving an artist's mood

Tags: echonest

I've noticed the EchoNest API offers a way of searching artists based on a particular mood e.g. Happy, sad, angry.  However I'm having a hard time retrieving a mood for a specific artist..

Answer (score 0):

Available mood terms to search for:

```
"type": "mood",
    "terms": [
        { "name": "happy" },
        { "name": "angry" },
        { "name": "sad" },
        { "name": "relaxing" },
        { "name": "excited"  }
```

My guess is that mood attributes weren't added to most of the artist, since these audio attributes were still experimental in 2013.